# PHP - Get all parameters from a function (even the optional one)

Tags: php

I want to get all parameters (passed or not) from a function.

Example:

```
<?php
    function foo($a, $b=1)
    {
         return $a-$b;
    }
?>
```

If I call

```
$test = func_get_args(foo(10));
var_dump($test);
```

I will have only an array with `[0] => 10`.

How can I have the value(s) of the optional parameter(s) even if I don’t pass it/them? (I know that `func_get_args` only returns passed parameters.)

**EDIT:** To be more precise, here is what I’m doing:

```
function insertLog($fct_name="-1", $type="-1", $error="-1", ....)
{
     // first thing
     $params = func_get_args();
     var_dump($params);
}
```

Comment: I think it will work if you call `func_get_args()` within the function, not outside of the function.

Comment: Thanks, I call it inside the function itself, i only got the passed parameters

Comment: Are you still using it he way you're using it above? It shouldn't look like this: `func_get_args(foo(10));` within your function. Try this instead: `print_r(func_get_args())` again, with no arguments passed to func_get_args(), and it's all within your function.

Comment: I edited my comment to be more precise on the way i use it.

Comment: @robotsushi: As the [documentation for `func_get_args()`](http://php.net/func_get_args) state: `The function returns a copy of the passed arguments only, and does not account for default (non-passed) arguments.`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can  accomplish this using the [`ReflectionFunction`](https://www.php.net/ReflectionFunction) function class.

```
function foo($a, $b=1)
{
    $arr = array();
    $ref = new ReflectionFunction(__FUNCTION__);
    foreach($ref->getParameters() as $parameter)
    {
        $name = $parameter->getName();
        $arr[$name] = ${$name};
    }
    print_r($arr);

    // ...
}
```

Calling the function:

```
foo(1);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 1
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/101348)

Comment: I will search in my own, but do this one have some php version restrictions ? (and just for information it does not reconize true/false state for a parameter but i can live with :)) thank you once again.

Comment: @Stv: It works on all versions above PHP5. And yes, it *can* detect types: https://eval.in/101366

Answer (score 2):

[func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

> Note: This function returns a copy of the passed arguments only, and does not account for default (non-passed) arguments.

Ive created a function called func_get_all_args which takes advantage of [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflection.php). It returns the same array as func_get_args but includes any missing default values.

```
function func_get_all_args($func, $func_get_args = array()){

    if((is_string($func) && function_exists($func)) || $func instanceof Closure){
        $ref = new ReflectionFunction($func);
    } else if(is_string($func) && !call_user_func_array('method_exists', explode('::', $func))){
        return $func_get_args;
    } else {
        $ref = new ReflectionMethod($func);
    }
    foreach ($ref->getParameters() as $key => $param) {

        if(!isset($func_get_args[ $key ]) && $param->isDefaultValueAvailable()){
            $func_get_args[ $key ] = $param->getDefaultValue();
        }
    }
    return $func_get_args;
}
```

Usage

```
function my_function(){

    $all_args = func_get_all_args(__FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
    call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, $all_args);
}

public function my_method(){

    $all_args = func_get_all_args(__METHOD__, func_get_args());
    // or
    $all_args = func_get_all_args(array($this, __FUNCTION__), func_get_args());

    call_user_func_array(array($this, __FUNCTION__), $all_args);
}
```

This could probably do with a bit of improvement such ac catching and throwing errors.